# Finding the probability that the relay network operates

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image: assuming that the relay network fails independently]

I interpreted as this:
(0.2n0.1)u(0.4n0.4n0.4n0.1)u(0.3n0.1)
Then I expanded it to:
(0.2n0.1)u(0.4n0.1)n(0.4n0.1)u(0.3n0.1)
Here I hooked up not knowing what to do. I don't know if my approach was wrong and I needed a different approach or maybe there's a theorem which I'm not aware. Somebody help in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1 - (1-0.3)\cdot (1-0.4\cdot 0.4)\cdot (1-0.2))\cdot 0.1 = (1-0.7\cdot 0.84\cdot 0.8)\cdot 0.1$

The point being, you need at least one of the parallel paths to work which is the opposite of all of the parallel paths not working.

Comment: If the network fails independently. Why do you apply this approach

Comment: If you have two components in sequence ---A----B---- with chances of failure $a$ and $b$ respectively you can simplify this as one component   ----X----  with chance of failure $ab$.  If you have two components in parallel with chance of failure $a$ and $b$ respectively you can simplify this as one component with chance of failure $(1-(1-a)(1-b))$ corresponding to the opposite event of $a$ and $b$ both working correctly.

Comment: The above was arrived at by simplifying the two $0.4$'s in sequence into one $0.16$... then simplifying the three parallel pieces into one piece, then finally simplifying the resulting component with the final $0.1$ component.

Comment: Having apply this method, I did not arrive at the answer as 0.865.

Comment: Make sure you understand what the question asks and how the information is displayed.  I had read it as $0.1$ chance of success for that component, but perhaps it is instead $0.1$ chance of failure.  Your post did not make it clear and is to blame.  The method otherwise works and you just have to flip the values used.

Comment: Still I  have not gotten your point. The solution according to you is not working for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122702/discussion-between-michael-umande-and-jmoravitz).